# Want to write a @RequestMapping for an URL different from my context path in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, saml, saml-2.0

I have my context path set as below in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so my url becomes http://localhost:8080/aaaadmin/service/dashboard

for which my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/dashboard")
    public ModelAndView dashboard() {
     ...
    }
```

now I want to catch the URL **http://localhost:8080/aaaadmin/saml/SingleLogout**

**so how am I supposed to write the controller where I don't want /service in the URL?**

If I write my controller as

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/saml/SingleLogout")
    public void singleLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       ...
    }
```

the the URL which is caught is http://localhost:8080/aaaadmin/***service***/saml/SingleLogout

but I dont want service in the URL.

Comment: I first though that this is not possible. But maybe this helps? https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/blog/configuring-a-dynamic-context-path-in-spring-boot

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose mine is a spring mvc project and not spring boot just to clarify.
secondly I have only this one URL which behaves differently so for one URL I don't want to write all that code. Please let me know if there is some other way. Please help.